# How to use a method from an application in an activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to compare the answer of a method in my Application class and DBHelper class. I do this in an activity. While I can use the method of the DBHelper class, I can't access the method of my Application class

My application class:

```
 public class thing extends Application {

          private String thing1;
          private String thing2;
          private String thing3;
          private String thing4;


          public String getVariable() {
                  return thing1 + thing2 + thing3 + thing4;                     
            }
```

My activity:

```
          public class solution extends AppCompatActivity {

               protected DBHelper DB;
                  @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 ...
                    }

                  }


            final Button solution = findViewById(R.id.solutionbutton);

            sol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) { 
                       DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                       if(db.getDODO("two").equals(thing.getVariable())){
                           ....
                        }
         });
         }}
```

Comment: `thing` isn't a static class and `getVariable()` isn't a static method. that's why you can't call `getVariable()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method of the application:

```
((thing) getApplication()).getVariable();
```